# Dynamic rankings in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rating-system

general "how do I do this?" question.

Say, I have a Rails app where users can browse books.  I want there to be a recommendations page that lists books recommended for that specific user based on an algorithm that integrates data from Facebook's Open Graph.  A simplified version of this algorithm would look something like:

a(Number of your facebook friends that have liked this book) +  b(total number of people that like this book)

Where a and b are weighting coefficients.

Where in rails would I calculate this formula to return the recommendations?  Is there a gem that helps with creating dynamic rankings?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to a rabbit hole. Enjoy the fall!

You're generally talking about Support Vector Machines. Here's some decent starting points:

- [Practical Machine Learning](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vy_zQ1-F0JI)
- http://matthewkirk.com/presentations/Support-Vector-Machines-with-Jruby.pdf
- https://github.com/hexgnu/rmw-svm